# How to create new row out of calculation across other rows in Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I want to create a new row via row calculations.
My DataFrame looks like this:

```
Para   01.21    02.21   03.21   
<48h     22      25      38 
>48h     0       1        3
```

I want to calc the percentage across each row such that:

**Goal**

```
Para   01.21    02.21   03.21   
<48h     22      25      38 
>48h     0       1        3
Perc.    0%      4%       8%
```

I had some ideas with appending a new DataFrame, but nothing really succesful.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are happy to modify the input DataFrame in place, this will produce the exact output you've requested:

```
df.loc['Perc.'] = (
    df.loc['>48h'] / df.loc['<48h']
).apply(lambda x: f"{x:.0%}")
```

This assumes that the first column in your printed output is the index of the DataFrame.

To unpack this a bit:

1. The assignment `df.loc['Perc.'] =`  will create a new row populated with the value on the right-hand side of the `=`.
2. `df.loc['>48h'] / df.loc['<48h']` computes the desired ratio, as a float
3. The `.apply` call calls a function on each element of the new row, to convert the raw percentage number to a string formatted in the manner you requested. To unpack this a little further:

   - `f"{x}"` converts `x` to a string (it is essentially equivalent to `str(x)`)
   - `f"{x:.0%}"` enhances the above by adding the `.0%` *format specifier*, which will display the value as a percentage with 0 decimal places (i.e. multiply by 100, round to 0 decimal places, and then add a `%` sign). There are various other format specifiers available for floating point data.

Note that if you want to do any further processing on the resulting value, I would recommend *not* doing step 3 - once you've converted your data into a string it obviously can't be e.g. multiplied by other data.

If you want the best of both worlds, keeping the internal value as a float ratio, but displaying them as a percentage, you can do this:

```
df.loc['Perc.'] = (
    df.loc['>48h'] / df.loc['<48h']
)

display_str = df.T.to_string(formatters={"Perc.": lambda x: f"{x:.0%}"})
print(display_str)
```

This will modify `df` to add the `Perc.` row, but its values will stay as the actual float ratio. Then `display_str` will be an appropriately-formatted string representation of the whole dataframe, including the percentage.

Note that `formatters` accepts a dict keyed by *column* names, not rows, so you must first transpose your data (`df.T`), the resulting output will be transposed:

```
   Para  <48h  >48h Perc.
0  1.21  22.0   0.0    0%
1  2.21  25.0   1.0    4%
2  3.21  38.0   3.0    8%
```

If you're working inside a Jupyter notebook, you can also use the `df.style.format` method to achieve something similar; calling

```
df.T.style.format({"Perc.": "{:.0%}"})
```

will return a `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler` object, but if you're in a Jupyter notebook, this will be rendered like a DataFrame with the relevant column formatted as above. Again though, this only works on a column-by-column basis, so you'll need to transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select rows:

```
#If first column is not index create it
#df = df.set_index('Para')


df.loc['Perc'] = df.loc['>48h'].div(df.loc['<48h']).mul(100).round()
print (df)
      01.21  02.21  03.21
Para                     
<48h   22.0   25.0   38.0
>48h    0.0    1.0    3.0
Perc    0.0    4.0    8.0
```

Better is transpose first, so is possible select by columns:

```
#If first column is not index create it
#df = df.set_index('Para')

df = df.T

df['Perc'] = df['>48h'].div(df['<48h']).mul(100).round()
print (df)
Para   <48h  >48h  Perc
01.21    22     0   0.0
02.21    25     1   4.0
03.21    38     3   8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
para = ['01.21', '02.21', '03.21']
a = np.array(([22, 25, 38]))
b = np.array(([0, 1, 3]))
df = pd.DataFrame([para, a, b], index=['Para', '<48h', '>48h'], columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2'])

perc = np.array(((b/a)*100))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([perc], index=['Perc.'], columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2'])
df = df.append(df2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        col0   col1     col2
Para   01.21  02.21    03.21
<48h      22     25       38
>48h       0      1        3
Perc.      0      4  7.89474
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not best practice to store data like this. Read [Hadley's tidy data paper](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

But in a line you could do it thusly.

```
df.loc['perc'] = df.iloc[2]/df.iloc[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

df.loc[key] = row

this is how we create new row in pandas data frame